# Eloquent JavaScript 4.4 Deep Comparison

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to teach myself some JavaScript via [Eloquent Javascript.](http://eloquentjavascript.net/index.html)

I'm on [chapter 4](http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html) practice 4.4 Deep comparison.
I've written my own code, passed all the tests given, even some tests I've made myself, but when I checked the solution, it was something totally different than what I had.

Could anyone tell me whether my code produces the same result as the solution, or some ideas of how to figure out whether if my code is right even when mine is something totally different than what the solution is, not just for this practice problem but also in future problems?

I'm just afraid of having a wrong idea and not realizing since my code works.

The question is:

> Write a function, deepEqual, that takes two values and returns true only if they are the same value or are objects with the same properties whose values are also equal when compared with a recursive call to deepEqual.
>
> To find out whether to compare two things by identity (use the === operator for that) or by looking at their properties, you can use the typeof operator. If it produces "object" for both values, you should do a deep comparison. But you have to take one silly exception into account: by a historical accident, typeof null also produces "object".

My code is:

```
function deepEqual(val1, val2) {
  if(typeof val1 !== typeof val2) return false;
  else if(typeof val1 !== "object") return val1 === val2;
  for(var event in val1){
    return deepEqual(val1[event], val2[event]);
  }
}
```

and the solution is:

```
function deepEqual2(a, b) {
  if (a === b) return true;
  
  if (a == null || typeof a != "object" ||
      b == null || typeof b != "object")
    return false;
  
  var propsInA = 0, propsInB = 0;

  for (var prop in a)
    propsInA += 1;

  for (var prop in b) {
    propsInB += 1;
    if (!(prop in a) || !deepEqual(a[prop], b[prop]))
      return false;
  }

  return propsInA == propsInB;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

1. You only test the first property in an object, because you have a `return` in your `for-in` loop. So when comparing objects, all your code does is check that first property.
2. If you kept a flag and returned the result after the loop, it would still have the issue that it only checks the properties in `a`; what if `b` has a property `a` doesn't have?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is the only way to check my code to come up with as many possible situations as possible?? I don't wanna be asking whether if I have the right code every time I try to solve some practice problems...

Comment: @user2099177: A combination of that, logically thinking through what your code is doing, and stepping through the code in the debugger to make sure it's doing what you think it's doing. :-)